# Conditional running count (cumulative sum) with reset in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate a running count (i.e., cumulative sum) that is conditional on other variables and that can reset for particular values on another variable.  I'm working in R and would prefer a `dplyr`-based solution, if possible.

I'd like to create a variable for the running count, `cumulative`, based on the following algorithm:

- Calculate the running count (`cumulative`) within combinations of `id` and `age`
- Increment running count (`cumulative`) by 1 for every subsequent `trial` where `accuracy = 0`, `block = 2`, and `condition = 1`
- Reset running count (`cumulative`) to 0 for each `trial` where `accuracy = 1`, `block = 2`, and `condition = 1`, and the next increment resumes at 1 (not the previous number)
- For each `trial` where `block != 2`, or `condition != 1`, leave the running count (`cumulative`) as `NA`

Here's a minimal working example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 age = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2),
                 block = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 trial = c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1),
                 condition = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1),
                 accuracy = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
)

id  age block   trial   condition   accuracy
1   1   1       1       1           0
1   1   1       2       1           0
1   1   2       1       1           0
1   1   2       2       1           0
1   1   2       3       1           0
1   1   2       4       2           0
1   1   2       5       1           0
1   1   2       6       1           1
1   1   2       7       1           0
1   1   2       8       1           0
1   2   2       1       1           0
```

The expected output is:

```
id  age block   trial   condition   accuracy    cumulative
1   1   1       1       1           0           NA
1   1   1       2       1           0           NA
1   1   2       1       1           0           1
1   1   2       2       1           0           2
1   1   2       3       1           0           3
1   1   2       4       2           0           NA
1   1   2       5       1           0           4
1   1   2       6       1           1           0
1   1   2       7       1           0           1
1   1   2       8       1           0           2
1   2   2       1       1           0           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to assign the value which we need based on our conditions. We then add an additional `group_by` condition using `cumsum` to switch values when the `temp` column 0. In the final `mutate` step we temporarily `replace` `NA` values in `temp` to 0, then take `cumsum` over it and put back the `NA` values again to it's place to get the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
    group_by(id, age) %>%
    mutate(temp = case_when(accuracy == 0 & block == 2 & condition == 1 ~ 1, 
                            accuracy == 1 & block == 2 & condition == 1 ~ 0, 
                            TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(id, age, group = cumsum(replace(temp == 0, is.na(temp), 0))) %>%
    mutate(cumulative = replace(cumsum(replace(temp, is.na(temp), 0)),
                          is.na(temp), NA)) %>%
    select(-temp, -group)


#    group    id   age block trial condition accuracy cumulative
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1     0     1     1     1     1         1        0         NA
# 2     0     1     1     1     2         1        0         NA
# 3     0     1     1     2     1         1        0          1
# 4     0     1     1     2     2         1        0          2
# 5     0     1     1     2     3         1        0          3
# 6     0     1     1     2     4         2        0         NA
# 7     0     1     1     2     5         1        0          4
# 8     1     1     1     2     6         1        1          0
# 9     1     1     1     2     7         1        0          1
#10     1     1     1     2     8         1        0          2
#11     1     1     2     2     1         1        0          1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Create a binary column based on `match`ing the `paste`d values of 'accuracy', 'block', 'condition' with that of the custom values, grouped by run-length-id of the binary column ('ind'), 'id' and 'age', get the cumulative sum of 'ind' and assign (`:=`) it to a new column ('Cumulative')

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, ind := match(do.call(paste0, .SD), c("121", "021")) - 1,
    .SDcols = c("accuracy", "block", "condition")
     ][, Cumulative := cumsum(ind), .(rleid(ind), id, age)
      ][, ind := NULL][]
#    id age block trial condition accuracy Cumulative
# 1:  1   1     1     1         1        0         NA
# 2:  1   1     1     2         1        0         NA
# 3:  1   1     2     1         1        0          1
# 4:  1   1     2     2         1        0          2
# 5:  1   1     2     3         1        0          3
# 6:  1   1     2     4         2        0         NA
# 7:  1   1     2     5         1        1          0
# 8:  1   1     2     6         1        0          1
# 9:  1   1     2     7         1        0          2
#10:  1   2     2     1         1        0          1
```

Comment: This answer is interesting, but it doesn't fully work with my data. I added a row to the data (see Trial 5).